# Rich Text Box Zoom transformation with scroll bars wpf

Tags: .net, wpf, richtextbox

I have RichTextbox with transformation as follows:

```
            <RichTextBox Name="mainRTB" AcceptsTab="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" TabIndex="0" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <SpellCheck.IsEnabled>False</SpellCheck.IsEnabled>
                <RichTextBox.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform 
                    ScaleY="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=slider1}" 
                    ScaleX="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=slider1}"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </RichTextBox.RenderTransform>
            </RichTextBox>
<Slider Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="slider1" Grid.Row="1" Minimum="1" Maximum="3" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Value="1.0"/>
```

The zoom of richtext box is controlled by the slider1.  The problem is that when the zoom factor is increased to more than 1 the scrollbars are lost on richtextbox, but the content is getting edited but not visible, I mean the content is below the visible screen, once the zoom is set back to normal I can see the content and scroll bars again, could you please suggest what I am required to do to get the things right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the RichTextBox inside a ScrollViewer.

Comment: scroll viewer only provides vertical scrolling, and even then the content is not still visible, I tried it.

Comment: The scroll viewer supports both types of scrolling, I use it to scroll images and linework around. I suspect you're issues with the scroll viewer are related more to the richtextbox than the scroll viewer.

Comment: I tried it again, but now I see that the scrollbars are getting big too.

Comment: The scrollbars getting larger means the scrollbars are attached to the richedit and are scaling with the scaletransform, not the scrollbars associated with the scrollviewer.